# Execute CommandLineRunner outside @SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This is based on https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/
I tried to move `demo()` in a different class in a different package (`Application` still on top of the filesystem hierarchy)

How do I make `demo()` run when i boot the project?

Application.java

```
package com.company.app

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
  }
}
```

CommandLineRunner.java

```
package com.company.app.runner

public class Test {

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo() {
        System.out.print("Run 1");
        return (args) -> {
            System.out.print("Run 2");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Add annotation @Configuration above Test class.

Comment: "SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration and ComponentScan with their default attributes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `@Configuration` to the `Test` class so that it is picked up when the classpath is scanned.

I haven't seen a Lambda for the CommandLineRunner before. Very nifty and saves having to create a class that specifically implements the CommandLineRunner.

Otherwise, you could implement CommandLineRunner to test and annotate as @Component.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("Run 2");
    }
}
```

*** Update ***
Answering the question in the comment with this update as I have more room to type...

`@SpringBootApplication` composes those other annotations as you indicated but those annotations are only applied to the specific class that it is defined on. The [`@Configuration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) annotation is telling Spring that the class defines beans that should be managed by the application context. The [`@ComponentScan`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) tells spring to look through the classpath for classes that have specific annotations (e.g. `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Configuration`) and then act on those classes based on the type of annotation. the [`@EnableAutoConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html) is the magic that loads appropriate beans based on the project dependencies (e.g. if mongo driver is on the classpath then create a `MongoTemplate`).

Comment: it works, but I don't get why "@SpringBootApplication" cannot do the job by itself, 

"SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration and ComponentScan with their default attributes" - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

Comment: So this is the reason why commandlinerunner works in this class, it has @Configuration